# How to parallelly process a collection of objects with celery workers running on multiple machines?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, celery, mongoengine

I have a few hundred thousand documents in a mongoDB collection accessible which follow a MongoEngine Schema called MyDoc. There is something (lets call it my_operation) that is to be run on each of these document. Also my_operation requires (just reads, does not alter) an OrderedDict called data_dict constructed via create_data_dict function. And I want to be able to run my_operation parallelly via celery workers.

The setup includes, django, mongo, mongoengine and celery.

Option1:

```
@celery.task()
def my_operation(my_doc_list):
   data_dict = create_data_dict()
   for doc in my_doc_list:
       do_something_to_doc(data_dict, doc)
       doc.save()

def create_data_dict():
   #blah blah blah
   return data_dict

#So I run everything like this:
batch_size = len(MyDoc.objects)/no_of_celery_workers
for b in xrange(0, len(MyDoc.objects), batch_size):
    my_operation.delay(MyDoc.objects[b:b+batch_size])
```

Option 2: my_operation takes data_dict and a MyDoc instance

```
@celery.task()
def my_operation(data_dict, my_doc):
   do_something_to_doc(data_dict, my_doc)
   my_doc.save()

def create_data_dict():
   #blah blah blah
   return data_dict

#So I run everything like this:
data_dict = create_data_dict()
celery.group([my_operation.s(data_dict, my_doc) for my_doc in MyDoc.objects]).apply_async()
```

Option 3:

```
@celery.task()
def my_operation(my_doc):
   data_dict = create_data_dict()
   do_something_to_doc(data_dict, my_doc)
   my_doc.save()

def create_data_dict():
   #blah blah blah
   return data_dict

#So I run everything like this:
celery.group([my_operation.s(my_doc) for my_doc in MyDoc.objects]).apply_async()
```

Option 4:

```
@celery.task()
def my_operation(my_doc):
   data_dict = get_data_dict()
   do_something_to_doc(data_dict, my_doc)
   my_doc.save()

def create_data_dict():
   #blah blah blah
   return data_dict

def get_data_dict():
   data_dict = cache.get("data_dict")
   if data_dict is None:
        data_dict = create_data_dict()
        cache.set("data_dict", data_dict)
   return data_dict

#So I run everything like this:
celery.group([my_operation.s(my_doc) for my_doc in MyDoc.objects]).apply_async()
```

Had Option1 worked, I wouldn't have asked the question probably, but alas I can't pass slices of queryset response, or querysets themselves to celery workers as they are not pickleable. Thats what the backtrace seemed to say mostly.

With Option2 I would end up passing the data_dict with every task and that somehow does not sound too appealing. And If I run celery workers on multiple machines, (which I do intend to do) data_dict, which essentially needs to be passed just once would consume a lot of network worthlessly.

And in case of Option3, data_dict is created afresh for every doc, which now seems to be a huge waste of processing power.

Option 4: I use cache to backup data_dict instead of recalculating it or retransmitting it with every doc. This sounds like the best idea, but there is a catch. The next time I want to do my_operation on all MyDocs, I would like the data_dict to be recalculated, regardless of whether it was there in the cache or not. Is there a way to achieve that?

The Question:
What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Superficially option 2 sounds just like option 1 - as you are passing the Object or its data around.

There are a lot of unknowns here but given that you mention in option 4 there could be some cache contention / race conditions I would probably opt for generating the data each time and just pass the object id, or if that is prohibitively expensive I would implement a collection to store the cached data and then clean the cache (findAndModify to stop race conditions) as part of the task.